# Unknown dots rendered into page - what causes them?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a demo [application](http://jsfiddle.net/k1nLqr2w/18/) here and in the upper left corners of the "tweets" there are dots and I have no idea where they come from. The code is written in Ember and the template looks like this

```
 <h2>Ember.js DEMO Tweet list</h2>

        <div class="tweets-list">
        <h2>Tweets</h2>
<button {{action 'changeAllTweets'}}>Change All Tweets</button>
<button {{action 'changeOneTweet'}}>Change One Tweet</button>
<div class="row input-wrap">
</div>
        {{#each this.model.topTweets as |model|}}
            <li class="media">
<div {{action 'bindNewModel' this}} class="row">
  <a class="pull-left" href="#"><img class="media-object" width="75" height="75" src={{model.avatar}}/></a>
  <div class="media-body">
  <h4 class="media-heading">{{model.favorites}}</h4>
  <p>{{model.text}}</p>
        </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-4">
<a href="#">Expand</a>
        </div>
<div class="col-xs-8">
<ul class="list-inline text-right">
<li href="#">Reply</li>
<li href="#">Retweet</li>
<li href="#">Favorite</li>
<li href="#">More</li>
        </ul>
        </div>
        </div>

</li>
{{/each}}

                </div>
```

P.S. The SHOW LIST button must be pressed for the list to show

Comment: Do you mean this leftover closing comment `-->`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're using list items, i.e. `<li>` tags. They're shown with bullet points by default.

First of all, you should only use `<li>` tags inside an ordered or unordered list (`<ol>` / `<ul>`). You should consider if list items are appropriate here. Maybe `<div>`s are more suitable?
If you want to use list items you should wrap them in a `<ul>` list and then get rid of the bullet points by applying the styling: `list-style-type: none`.
Changing the `display` style of the list item will also get rid of the bullet point.

Answer (score 1):

These are the list item markers. Add list-style:none; to the ul, and they will disappear. 
Edit: I see that you are also missing the ul itself. The wrapping ul does not exist. These are just list items. Add the opening ul before the each statement and closing after it. And in case the list style none rule. 
I'm on mobile and can't edit the fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

There is HTML structural error. 
Wrap the `<li class="media">` with an `<ul>` tag. I can assume you are using Bootstrap. If yes then wrap the `<li>` tag with `<ul class="list-group">` and add `list-group-item` class to the `<li>` tag like this: `<li class="media list-group-item">`